# ReferenceError Kill

Tags: javascript, events

I'm currently searching a solution to a problem with `onerror`.

I want to kill a `ReferenceError` event to keep my script working.

i've tried with:

```
window.onerror=function(event){alert('called');event.stopPropagation();return true;};
```

I'm getting the alert, but my event is still dispatched and stops my script.

How can I really stop this type of event?

Comment: How can your script work with ReferenceErrors ( killed or not )? O_o You know what you should do? Fix your script!

Comment: You expect to just "catch" this error and continue with execution of the same script? Or just others embedded on your page?

Comment: No, i'm building my own error report. It's work fine with all other, but ReferenceError block directly... i want to kill it to make my script analyse the error.

Comment: @freakish I admit, Simons idea is somehow twisted, but it may be useful if you're embedding unknown 3rd party scripts that may have some reference errors.

Comment: @SimonPaitrault Why are you using `.onerror` for that instead of wrapping the code in try..catch block?

Comment: @WTK I would throw out such 3rd party script. Come on, ReferenceErrors are the easiest to spot and fix.

Comment: @freakish Use your imagination, what if you are building a system in which users can post their scripts and you want to catch and show them those ReferenceErrors without affecting other scripts. I imagine there may be use cases for this. Although, so we are clear, I wouldn't do it this way.

Comment: @WTK How would such system work? It would probably AJAX in the script ( otherwise you can't wrap it in `try{}catch{}` block ). In that case everything is happening in a seperate "thread" ( not really a thread, rather asynchronous code block ), so if it crashes it won't affect other scripts. Even more - you would do that in seperate iframe, because working script can mess your scripts as well. I'm telling you - this is an overkill.

Comment: @freakish " If a user knows how to write and upload a script, then he will also know how to debug it" - if that was true, half of stackoverflow wouldn't even exist. Average user knows how to copy and paste script without much knowledge why and how it does work (or doesn't).

Comment: @WTK True, that's why I removed the line. :] Anyway the rest of my comment is valid.